# Hide button for new row in Access 2013 continuous form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a continuous form in Access with `Allow Additions` set to `Yes`. I'm trying to enable or disable a deletion button depending on if the user has filled in data in that record. In other words, I want to hide the button for only the blank record at the bottom of the form.

I tried the following in the Form_Current event but it enables or disables all buttons at the same time, and it only runs when I click on a record. I need it to run immediately and update when I add a new row.

```
If Me.NewRecord Then
    btnDelete.Visible = False
Else
    btnDelete.Visible = True
End If
```

EDIT: with working code.

```
If Me.NewRecord Then
    'show error message
    MsgBox ("Unable to delete empty row.")
Else
    'deletion code
End If
```

Comment: Don't think that's possible in continuous forms - everything looks the same. You might be able to add code to the btnDelete_Click event that checks for Me.NewRecord and just exits the sub

Comment: @dbmitch Thank you! I edited my question with the working code. If you post your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Will do - thanks for the follow-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous forms won't allow that - everything looks the same.

You might be able to add code to the `btnDelete_Click` event that checks for `Me.NewRecord` and just exits the sub

Answer (score 0):

Here is the above code with handling when the user starts entering data in the "add" row and then clicks delete on that row.

```
If Me.NewRecord Then
    'code to undo/clear partially entered new record
    If Me.Dirty Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
    End If
    
Else
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this xxxx record?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
    End If
End If
```